# Why is WPF application running in debug mode slow?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, performance, debugging

I know that running applications in DEBUG (build configuration) thru the visual studio adds a level of overhead but I have a WPF application that I am testing out that is painfully slow in its execution and other functions such as drag/drop of items.  When I run the application in Release mode it performs like one would expect, very quickly and without hesitation.  I've set up no special debugging parameters or any other watches, settings or breakpoints that would interrupt the application.

Has anyone else run across an issue like this or is there possibly just some setting that can be adjusted?  It's not really an issue more of a why is this happening...

thanks.

Comment: When you say DEBUG and RELEASE, are you referring to the build configurations, or whether or not a debugger is attached?

Comment: build configuration; post updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The garbage collector is much less aggressive in debug mode.

Try watching the memory usage in task manager, the VM Size column is often the most useful.

See if during the slow operations a lot of memory gets released - this will indicate that the collector hasn't bothered doing much work for a while and then has had to kick in a do a larger clean up.

Answer (score 1):

You might check your Output and Immediate windows. You're might be getting a lot of messages thrown in there, especially if you're getting binding errors.

Comment: The project I was working on had broken font resource references in the xaml files which lead to lots of FileNotFound exceptions. Apparently some exceptions slow down the startup, but it will still start eventually.